# Cheap and easy way of coating breakout board/wires black?

Tags: conformal-coating

Part of my housing for an arduino based project leaves the back of a screen breakout board and several wires visible through a grill and I need to cover these in black to minimise visibility as the housing itself is black.

The board itself is already conformal coated out of the box, and the only exposed electrical part would be my solder joints between a ribbon cable and the board.

Is there any type of off the shelf paint (brushed or spray) I can safely use to disguise these? I have some Rust-Oleum Painter's Touch acrylic black from another project, would that be suitable?

Comment: electricians tape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using "brush on electrical tape"?

[https://www.amazon.com/Gardner-Bender-LTB-400-Electrical-Waterproof/dp/B000FPAN2K](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FPAN2K)

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was after

Comment: Adding for any UK people looking for similar https://www.sotabeams.co.uk/liquid-electrical-tape/ (Also the same company that makes Plasti-dip, that I should have thought of!)

Answer (score 1):

Spray paint.  model paint. Craft paint.  Sharpie. Electrical tape. Split Wire loom.  Wire loom mesh. Heat shrink tubing. Duct tape.

Comment: A piece of black paper/cardboard.

Comment: Sharpie had occurred to me and was going to be my back up plan :)